# Xcode5 error : Warning attempt to present <View> on <OtherView> while presentation is in progress

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, xcode5

I am still a noob when it comes to making applications for iOS and I don't understand why I am getting a certain error. For my current project I am trying to switch views but I cannot get it to work and I do not really understand why. I followed this tutorial for the button(http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ph3XhJD8QAI) and although the tutorial is older, it still works. I had to edit some of the code to make sure that it worked for Xcode 5 though. Every time I press the button to switch the views I get an error that reads "**Warning: Attempt to present < SecondView: 0xc918d50 > on < SeriouslyFunnyView: 0xc91a130 > while a presentation is in progress!"** and the screen in the iPhone Simulator just goes black. I am also using Storyboard, i'm not sure if that is relevant to the situation or not. Can anyone possibly tell me what I am doing wrong ? Let me know if I need to add more code for clarification ! Thanks in advance for the help

Here is my code for the button that switches views

```
-(IBAction)SwitchView:(id)sender {
    SecondView *second = [[SecondView alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:second animated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You must dismiss completely a view before present another. Try with:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion: ^{
    SecondView *second = 
          [[SecondView alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    controller.modalTransitionStyle = UITableViewStylePlain;
    [self presentViewController:second animated:YES completion:nil];
}];
```

Comment: I am working on a single view application so the Tableview stuff doesn't really work in my case. I also copied your exact code and ended up with more errors than I originally started with

Comment: Sorry. I din't see you're using storyboard. Check if you're calling two times the viewcontroller, once from the button and once from the segue.

Comment: Not really sure what you mean by this, can you clarify a little ? Sorry I'm still new at this. I'm pretty sure I'm doing it right...or so I think

Comment: Well I'll try to explain, but usually I don't work with storyboards. In your storyboard, have you triggered a segue from the SwitchViewButon to the new view controller? If so, I think that when you click the button the segue will be triggered, but also again due to the IBAction.

Comment: Ok, so what should I do in order to stop this from happening ?

Comment: Perform the segue to the next controller from the previous one (the controller which contain the button) not from the button. That is delete the segue from the button and recreate from the controller. also give this segue the button identifier.

Comment: Sorry for all the questions but how exactly would I do that ?

Comment: From the viewController icon below of the viewcontroller which contains the button create a segue to the new vien controller. Then give an identifier to that segue. Finally, change the content of your IBAction method to [self performSegueWithIdentifier:yourIdentifierSegue sender:self];

Comment: I did exactly as you said. I gave my identifier the name of shareMenu and I got an error saying 'use of undeclared identifier shareMenu'

Comment: Have you put @"sharedMenu"?

Comment: THAT WORKED ! now how would I exit the new view ? Do I just create a segue back to the original view controller and add a back button or something ?

Answer (score 0):

comment the body of switchview, and check whether any controller is presented on click of switchview.. that looks silly but may be it'd b helpful to find out which controller is in progress... i'm also not used to storyboards ,, so .. hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

 // TODO: make this all threaded?
 // crop the image to the bounds provided
 img = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
 NSLog(@"orig image size: %@", [[NSValue valueWithCGSize:img.size] description]);

 // save the image, only if it's a newly taken image:
 if ([picker sourceType] == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera) {
     UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img, nil, nil, nil);
 }

 // self.image_View.image = img;
 // self.image_View.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

NSLog(@"Picker has returned");
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES
                         completion:^{
                            ModalViewController *sampleView = [[ModalViewController alloc] init];
                            [self presentModalViewController:sampleView animated:YES];
                         }];
```

}